# How to theme checkout completion page in Drupal Commerce

Tags: theming, commerce

I'm having a problem with theming the checkout completion page. My designer gave me a layout that will show all of the order details in that page(nearly same as the checkout review pane). I already googled it and all of the links that I tried is not working. Please see the links below

[theming checkout pages in Drupal commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18234/theming-checkout-pages-in-drupal-commerce)
http://theoleschool.com/blog/templating-commerce-order-completion-pane

Is there any tpl.php file that I need to include? or hooks to achieve my goal?

Thanks GUys

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search yielded this result:

[Templating the Commerce Order Completion Pane](http://theoleschool.com/blog/templating-commerce-order-completion-pane)

> Turns out that's a fairly simple task thanks to
>   hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter. The function passes the
>   variable $checkout_panes by reference which contains an array of
>   checkout pane arrays. This function is going to allow us to redefine
>   the function that the checkout completion pane is looking to for
>   output.

Comment: Thanks @2pha. That's the one that I was trying since yesterday. I'm having a problem with my_module_completion_message_pane_checkout_form(). I tried to leave a dpm() on that function and it seems it doesn't  run that function()