# Add product information with variation in cart

Tags: views, commerce

I sell product which actually are product variation.
In the cart or the checkout , all I can see are products variation information ( size price etc..) In this view I need to see the product, with the title, image, ...

Are there any solution for that ?

Thank you.

Comment: See if this question gives you enough of a starting point: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18234/theming-checkout-pages-in-drupal-commerce. I have a project where we did this, but I wasn't the developer on the commerce bits of it, so I'm reluctant to comment in too much detail lest I steer you wrong.

Comment: Yeah but my problem is within the view not the template. Maybe some php in the view to get parent info...but that seems too much , I hoped for a drupal way to do it.